Save a User Modified PDF to a blob
I have a website where a User can view and modify a PDF via embed.
<embed src="/pdfs/modified_dnd_char_sheet.pdf" width="1000" height="800" type="application/pdf">

I would like to save the modified pdf to a blob.
But I'm having a problem actually figuring out how to grab the bytes from the modified pdf.
static async Task Save(string[] args)
{
    string fileUrl = "https://example.com/path/to/your/modified_dnd_char_sheet.pdf"; // Replace with the URL of the PDF
    string savePath = @"C:\path\to\save\modified_dnd_char_sheet.pdf"; // The local path where you want to save the PDF

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Get the PDF file from the URL
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(fileUrl);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read the content as a byte array
            byte[] pdfBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            // Save the PDF to the specified file path
            await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(savePath, pdfBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("PDF saved successfully.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


"how to grab the bytes from the modified pdf" Where is this file located? How does the user modify the PDF and submit their changes?

You are using HttpClient wrong, too.
